# Obfuscate4e: how to retrace using retrace.jar in obfuscate4e

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, obfuscation, proguard

I am developing a RCP application using Eclipse Indigo on Windows7. I have added Obfuscate4e plugin in my Eclipse Indigo IDE. ( check at:- http://code.google.com/p/obfuscate4e/ ) 
I have also obfuscated my RCP application using proguard as mentioned at:- http://code.google.com/p/obfuscate4e/wiki/GettingStarted
Now I want to Retrace the stacktrace using retrace.jar inside Eclipse. How to use the retrace.jar with Obfuscate4e in Eclipse IDE?

I could retarce the stacktrace on command prompt but want to know if this can be done inside IDE (in order to automate the process of retracing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that retracing inside Eclipse is not possible.
A gui is available for retace using proguardgui.jar as shown in the image
[image: proguard gui] but since it's not working for me I am doing it through command prompt.